# How to prove R/Z $\backsimeq$R/2Z

Tags: group-theory

Here is my thought.

$R/Z$ = { $\dots$ { $\dots$ {-1 + $r_1$}, {0 + $r_1$}, {1 + $r_1$}, $\dots$ }, { $\dots$ {-1 + $r_2$}, {0 + $r_2$}, {1 + $r_2$}, $\dots$ } $\dots$ }

$R/2Z$ = { $\dots$ { $\dots$ {-2 + $r_1$}, {0 + $r_1$}, {2 + $r_1$}, $\dots$ }, { $\dots$ {-2 + $r_2$}, {0 + $r_2$}, {2 + $r_2$}, $\dots$ } $\dots$ }

So let $\alpha: R/Z \longrightarrow R/2Z $ as $Z + r\longmapsto$ 2Z + r

Then $\alpha$ is bijective.

Let

$a =$ { .... {-1 + $r_1$}, {0 + $r_1$}, {1 + $r_1$} .... } $\in R/Z$

$b =$ { .... {-1 + $r_2$}, {0 + $r_2$}, {1 + $r_2$} .... } $\in R/Z$

Assume

$\alpha(a) =$ { .... {-2 + $r_1$}, {0 + $r_1$}, {2 + $r_1$} .... }

$ab = $ { .... {-1 + $r_1$ + $r_2$}, {0 + $r_1$ + $r_2$}, {1 + $r_1$ + $r_2$} .... }

Then

$\alpha(a)\alpha(b) = $ { .... {-2 + $r_1$}, {0 + $r_1$}, {2 + $r_1$} .... } $\ast$ { .... {-2 + $r_2$}, {0 + $r_2$}, {2 + $r_2$} .... } $=$ { .... {-2 + $r_1$ + $r_2$}, {0 + $r_1$ + $r_2$}, {2 + $r_1$ + $r_2$} .... } $= \alpha(ab)$

So it's isomorphic.

Is my solution true? If so, how to generalize this?

Comment: Instead of $ab$ and $\alpha(a) \alpha(b)$, you probably mean $a + b$ and $\alpha(a) + \alpha(b)$ as you're looking at $\Bbb R$ (and its quotients) as an additive group.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your map $\alpha$ is not even well-defined. For instance, $1/2 = 3/2$ in $\Bbb R/\Bbb Z$, but you're specifying that the image of (the residue class of) $1/2$ is (the residue class) of $1/2$ and that the image of $3/2$ is $3/2$, but $1/2 \neq 3/2$ in $\Bbb R / 2\Bbb Z$.

You can get away with this by defining $\alpha(r + \Bbb Z) = r + 2 \Bbb Z$ for all $r \in [0,1)$, which works because every element of $\Bbb R/\Bbb Z$ has a unique representant in $[0,1)$.

However, then your map $\alpha$ is not surjective: it does not have, for instance (the residue class of) $3/2$ in its image. It also is not a homomorphism of groups: $1/2 + 1/2 = 0$ in $\Bbb R/\Bbb Z$, but $\alpha(1/2) + \alpha(1/2)= 1/2 + 1/2 = 1 \neq 0$ in $\Bbb R/2 \Bbb Z$.

Also, instead of working with residue classes all the time, it is easier to define a suitable surjective homomorphism $\alpha \colon \Bbb R \to \Bbb R$. Then compose this with the projection $\pi \colon \Bbb R \to \Bbb R / 2 \Bbb Z$. Your choice of $\alpha$ then should be such that $\pi \circ \alpha$ has kernel $\Bbb Z$ (which means that you have to prove that $\alpha^{-1}(2 \Bbb Z) = \Bbb Z$). Then $\pi \circ \alpha$ induces the desired isomorphism $\Bbb R / \Bbb Z \to \Bbb R / 2 \Bbb Z$.

Now, which homomorphism $\alpha \colon \Bbb R \to \Bbb R$ maps the integers to the even numbers?

Comment: It's not that $\alpha$ isn't surjective or not a group homomorphism. It's that $\alpha$ isn't a well-defined function: $r + \mathbf{Z} = 1 + r + \mathbf{Z}$ but $r + 2\mathbf{Z} \ne 1 + r + 2\mathbf{Z}$.

Comment: @T.Gunn I was willing to forgive that by always taking $r \in [0,1)$, but you're right.

Comment: Is $\alpha$ just $r = 2r$?

Comment: Yes, $r \mapsto 2r$ works.